# Integral from normal variable.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Supposoe we have normal variable $ N(\mu_t, \sigma_t^2 ) $.

Let's define X = $\int_0^T N(\mu_t, \sigma_t^2 ) dt$.

**Is X also a normal variable?**

---

> It's simple to check that expectation of X is simply $\int_0^T \mu_t dt$ as
> $\mathbb{E} (\int)  = \int (\mathbb{E})$.
>
> BUT it is not the case for variance as
>
> $\mathbb{V} (X) = \mathbb{V} (\int_0^T N(\mu_t, \sigma_t^2 ) dt)
> \approx \mathbb{V} (\sum_i N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2 ) \triangle) =
> > \mathbb{V} (\sum_i N(\mu_i, \triangle^2\sigma_i^2 ) )$
>
> Entering the sum into normal variable:
>
> $\mathbb{V} (N(\ \sum_i \mu_i, \ \sum_i \triangle^2\sigma_i^2 \ ) ) =
>  \sum_i \triangle^2\sigma_i^2$
>
> Now I would like to get back to integrals and do something like this:
>
> $\sum_i \triangle^2\sigma_i^2 \approx \int_0^T \triangle \sigma_t^2
>  dt, \ \triangle \to 0$
>
> But it seems weird...
>
> Could someone help me to find the good variance and figure out where I
> was wrong?

Comment: Does the notation $N(\mu_t, \sigma_t^2)$ refer to the probability density function of a normal random variable $Y_t$ with mean $\mu_t$ and variance $\sigma_t^2$ or are you using it to refer to the random variable, $Y_t$, itself?

Comment: Unless the process $\{N_t:=N(\mu_t,\sigma_t^2)\}$ is "nice", the $\omega$-wise integral does not make sense.